# retrieve cck field for form_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I would like to retrieve a cck field "field_info" in my form alter to insert into another table when user is submitting. This doesn't seem to work.

```
//mymodule_form_alter() implemented
       function mymodule_form_mysubmit{

            $test = $form['field_info']['#value'];
        //insert stuff code
    }
```

Is there any mistake in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say `module_form_alter()` is implemented, but just to confirm, you need to have the following in it:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_mysubmit';
```

Assuming you do, to get the value of field_info, your submit function should look like:

```
function mymodule_form_mysubmit($form, &$form_state) {
  $test = $form_state['values']['field_info'][0]['value'];
}
```

`$form_state` contains the current state of the form being submitted. CCK always assumes that there could be multiple values for a field, so it always puts things in an array (hence `['field_info'][0]`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
        $test = $form['field_info'][0]['#value'];
```

Comment: The $form array is not safe, as it contains the structure of the form, and not necessarily the current form's values. In some circumstances—like when drupal_execute submits the form—the value will not be there. Use $form_state: it'll always contain the value, and it's the Drupal Way.